# Re-formatting (appending text to) \paragraph{}

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I would like to change the appearance of `\paragraph{}` (particularly the space between the end of the heading and the beginning of the text) to look more like

```
\noindent\textbf{Paragraph heading} --- Lorem ipsum dolor
```

I have been googling for an hour, and I found all sort of ways for changing the spaces around the heading, but I could not find how to append something to it.

**NOTE**: The three dashes are supposed to be turned into an em-dash, they are not there to signify white space. Sorry if it was not clear the first time around.

Comment: Are those dashes supposed to represent a space or an em-dash?

Comment: They are supposed to be an em-dash.

Comment: I see. Then, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[\hspace{0.5em}\nolinebreak---]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}

\begin{document} 

\paragraph{A test paragraph} Some test text

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Without packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-0.5em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
\let\@svsec\@empty
\else
\refstepcounter{#1}%
\protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
\fi
\@tempskipa #5\relax
\ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
\begingroup
#6{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
\interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
\endgroup
\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
\fi
#7}%
\else
\def\@svsechd{%
#6{\hskip #3\relax
\@svsec #8}%
\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
\fi
#7}}%
\fi
\@xsect{#5}
\ifnum#2=4\relax---\ \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\paragraph{A test paragraph} Some test text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Just one thing: the space to the left of the em-dash does not seem to stretch like the one to the right.

Comment: @Morpheu5 I don't quite understand. Do you mean the spaces are not equal?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: Ah, I added a \hspace{.5em} before the ~--- and it looks good now. Are those spaces supposed to stretch at all?

Comment: @Morpheu5 I introduced the same modification in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
\newcommand[1]{\mypar}{\paragraph{#1}\hspace{3em}}
```

or

```
\newcommand[1]{\mypar}{\paragraph{#1}~---}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear that the '---' were supposed to be an em-dash.

Comment: I'll update my answer for the sake of completeness. However, Gonzalo's way is much better than mine.